# SQL - join TWO tables and get record from B table if exist, else from A table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, A and B. If record is exist in table B (checking by ID), then I want to get this record from this table (table B). If not exist in table B, then I want to get this record from table A (so most important is getting from table B but if not exist, then get from table A).

After that, I want to join these records (from table A or table B) with table C by ID (from table A or B). Is it possible to do it in one query?

Example:

table C:

```
|ID|STATUS|

|1 |4     |
```

Table A:

```
|ID|SOME_VALUE|

|1 |1         |
```

Table B:

```
|ID|SOME_VALUE|

|1 |1         |
```

And now, when I want get record of ID = 1, query should check if this ID exist in table B (in my example, record ID = 1 exist in table B).
We know this record is in table B so we should join table B (record ID = 1) with table status, by record ID = 1.

```
SELECT a.*, c.* FROM `table_A` a LEFT JOIN `table_C` ON a.id = c.id WHERE c.id = 1;
```

But I don't know how to add to this query checking if this record exist in table B (if exist, get from table B, if not - get from table A).

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and those backticks are invalid standard SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have a value in table `A`, this should do it:

```
SELECT t.id, C.status FROM (
  SELECT 
    A.id, coalesce(B.some_value, A.some_value) as some_value
  FROM
    A
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
) t
  INNER JOIN C on C.id = t.some_value;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1762f35/4

p.s. I'm not sure I got your data model right, though

**UPD:**

In case you need to join by `id`, not `some_value`, here's another fiddle (it's the same approach): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2be17/1

Comment: your outermost inner join with `C` is doing by `some_value`... Maybe it should be by `id` as well?

Comment: @pkuderov yeah, I'm not sure about that one too. I hope question author will elaborate a bit more on his data model

Comment: It should by id. Every three tables have row ID and it could join by this row.
But I have one problem - table A and table B contain 72 rows, I can't write every row so I need to use `*`. Can you change in your case row names with `*`? Name of row which save id is `filter_id` (you can save it by `id`, I can change it in my project, it's not problem)

Comment: @PavelK hm, I'm not sure what you mean by `change row names with *`. I think you probably meant _column_ names. Did you mean that you have alot of _columns_ (meaning, not only some_value)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my english is not well. Can you change column names in your query with `*` ? In my table is 72 columns, I can't wire every column name in query

Comment: @PavelK no worries. I don't think it's possible in my approach without dirty hacks or needless subqueries (atleast I couldn't come up with an elegant one), because it all depends on `COALESCE` function, which expects explicit column names. You can pass `id` there to check if row exists, but then you can't select all values without further subquerying

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE, t2.STATUS
FROM (
   -- Get record from B. If record exists in B then next query 
   -- doesn't return the record.
   SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE
   FROM B
   WHERE ID = 1

   UNION ALL

   -- Get record from A. The query returns nothing if the record exists 
   -- in B.
   SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE
   FROM A
   WHERE ID = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE ID = 1)
) AS t1
INNER JOIN C AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**Edit:** A generic version of the above query is:

```
SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE, t2.STATUS
FROM (
   -- Get record from B. If record exists in B next query returns nothing.
   SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE
   FROM B

   UNION ALL

   -- If record doesn't exist in B previous query returns nothing
   SELECT ID, SOME_VALUE
   FROM A
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
) AS t1
INNER JOIN C AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I change table rows names from `ID, SOME_VALUE, t2.STATUS` to `*, t2.*` and query return nothing (0 results). The record of ID = 1 exist in table A, B and C